# Configuration error while adding new layouts

Tags: android

I have created new layouts for different screen resolutions, each in its own folder with correct suffix. However when I try to build the app I get this:

```
error: invalid configuration '1200x1920' (C:\Users\...\app\src\main\res\layout-1200x1920\activity_welcome_new_new.xml).
error: invalid configuration '1440x2560' (C:\Users\...\app\src\main\res\layout-1440x2560\activity_welcome_new_new.xml).
```

I have created these layout configuration with the android new>layout resource file so there should not be any human error involved with the folder naming

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Those are not proper resource folders. You can find more here https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources#AlternativeResources about the allowed qualifiers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The names of your folders are incorrect. They should be something like

```
layout-w1200dp-h1920dp
layout-w1440dp-h2560dp
```

Nevertheless, on Android you define your screen size not in pixels, but in dp -> density independent pixel. You can read about it [here.](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources#Dimension)

So, I think your screen sizes are too big and e.g. if you have a XXXHDPI phone the layout folder can look like:

```
layout-w360dp-h640dp
```

instead of

```
layout-w1440dp-h2560dp
```

Comment: Thanks, the exact resolution, even though it was accepted by the IDE, could not pass the build, so I have changed the suffix and it works.